# How to Serialize an Attribute but dont persist it using spring data?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

Im studying spring data + JPA, and created a query like:

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT g.group, sum(ball) as sum from person ... group by ...", nativeQuery=false)
    List<Group> BallPerGroup();
}
```

The return is:

```
sum    |     group
10     |   group 1
5      |   group 2
6      |   group 3
```

I have a Entity Group:

```
public class Group{
    @Id @Genera...
    private Integer id;
    private String group;

    //getters and setter

}
```

I have an Entity Person:

```
public class Person{
    @Id @Genera...
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer ball;

    @OneToMany
    private Group group;


    //getters and setter

}
```

I want to have an attribute called sum, that spring data can serialize but dont persist it. In mean words, i dont want to see 'sum' column in my database.

I already tried `@transient` but it was null.

How can i do it?

Comment: Show me repository method signature

Comment: You can use a DB view or a Provider extension (such Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation), as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407889/prefered-way-to-map-a-result-set-with-entity-and-count-using-spring-data/43411008#43411008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Antoniossss! Editing his answer:

> What you want is to make a projection, and this is how you make
>   projections in spring data. You can go up that hill and use proper
>   constructor for that:
>
> @Query(SELECT new full.qualified.name.of.class(sum as sum, ..... other arguments) from ... )

This is what i did and worked as expected.

So, i add an attribute with `@transient` annotation:

```
public class Group{
    @Id @Genera...
    private Integer id;
    private String group;

    @Transient
    private Integer sum;

    //getters and setter

}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17686603)

Comment: This is exactly what i did... `@Query(SELECT new full.qualified.name.of.class(sum as sum, ..... other arguments) from ... )` and  add an attribute with `@transient` annotation:

Answer (score 1):

Change that class to `interface`, and then declare your method like this

```
    public interface GroupInterface { 
privte String groupName; 
private Long sum
}
```

....

```
@Query(SELECT sum(a) as sum, groupNameColumn as groupName from ... inner join group ... group by ...
public List<GroupInterface> getMyResults(add some arguments if needed)
```

notice that query must return 2 columns

Comment: I dont want create a dataholder for that (an interface)... I would like to add an attribute in Group Entity, but dont persist it and serialize when available

Comment: What you want is to make a projection, and this is how you make projections in spring data. You can go up that hill and use proper constructor for that `@Query(SELECT new full.qualified.name.of.class(sum as sum, ..... other arguments)`

Comment: Are you saying that is not possible to have an attribute that can be serialized but dont persist?

Comment: It is with `@Transient` (or ommiting @Column) but it will not be initialized like you wish it would. **It will not persist** like you want, but what you truly want is to take value from query projection, and this will not work that way. The only way is to use custom contructor and `SELECT new ....` expression, but this is awefull IMHO

Comment: I already thought about it before post... But in my mind, create a dataholder file for it is so expensive....

Comment: Keep track of every required field in query string is even worst.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157109/discussion-between-brenno-leal-and-antoniossss).