# Returning complex objects from Spring Data @Query

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm writing a Questionnaire application (Java, Spring Boot, SQL) and I have a working query for returning the count of each answer in the database for specified questionnaire:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new org.project.domain.AnswerCount(a.value, count(a)) FROM "
            + "Answer a WHERE a.questionnaire = :questionnaire GROUP BY a.value")
    List<AnswerCount> findAnswerCountByQuestionnair(@Param("questionnaire") Questionnaire questionnaire);
```

Now what I would like to do is to group these AnswerCounts by what question they are answers to and store that in a list of QuestionResponseData objects. I could do it in Java code by some stream grouping methods, but I would prefer to do it directly in the query for speed.

Is that even possible, and what would be the best way to do that?

Here are the relevant parts of the models:

```
public class AnswerCount {
    private String answer;
    private long count;
}
```

.

```
public class QuestionResponseData {

    private String question;
    private String type;
    private List<AnswerCount> answers;
}
```

.

```
/**
 * A Answer.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "answer")
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "jhi_value", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

    @ManyToOne
    private Respondant respondant;

    @ManyToOne
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;
}
```

.

```
/**
 * A Question.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "question")
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "jhi_type")
    private QuestionType type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Questionnaire> questionnaires = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I'm thinking something similar to this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new QuestionResponseData(q.text, q.type, answers) FROM "
+ "(SELECT new org.project.domain.AnswerCount(a.value, count(a)) as answerCount FROM "
+ "Answer a WHERE a.questionnaire = :questionnaire GROUP BY a.value") answers, "
+ "Question q WHERE answers.answerCount.question = q "
+ "GROUP BY answerCount.question")
```

but that obviously doesn't work...

Is it possible?

Comment: You can handle at the database by defining a database view and mapping as secondary table to the count simply becomes another property of Question(naire) and can used to filter, sort etc.. Alternatively you can use a Projection. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407889/prefered-way-to-map-a-result-set-with-entity-and-count-using-spring-data/43411008#43411008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefered way to map a result set with entity and count using Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407889/prefered-way-to-map-a-result-set-with-entity-and-count-using-spring-data)